# Is there a way to remap Caps_Lock to be the escape key on vscode's vim?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, vscodevim

#### Problem

I want to use Caps_Lock as the key to exit insert mode in Visual Studio code's vim extension. I have already remapped the keys in Xorg with Xmodmap, but Visual studio doesn't seem to really matter.

#### My VScode settings

As you can see, I already tried with `"vim.insertModeKeyBindings"`, but it only disables the Escape key, leaving me thinking that Caps_lock has another key name/keysym, but I can't seem to find it.

```
{
    "editor.fontFamily": "'Inconsolata-g for Powerline'",
    "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "liveshare.authenticationProvider": "GitHub",
    "vim.enableNeovim": true,
    "code-runner.enableAppInsights": false,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
            "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
        }
    ],
    "workbench.colorTheme": "BeardedTheme Anthracite",
    "extensions.autoUpdate": "onlyEnabledExtensions",
    "vim.vimrc.enable": true,
    "vim.vimrc.path": "$HOME/.config/nvim/init.vim",
    "editor.fontWeight":"bold", 
    "vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
        {
            "before": ["<Esc>"],
            "after": ["<Caps_Lock>"]
        }
   ]
}
```

Another thing i'd like to address is that i already have `j,k` and their combinations to exit insert mode. Is that a default?

---

Huge thanks in advance to anybody offering to help!!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Vim so there is no need for a "vim" tag.

Comment: How is this not related with Vim?

Comment: You are not using Vim.

Comment: True, I'm using NeoVim, thanks for noting!

Comment: Maybe just `Capslock`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61451308/836330 for some variations on capslock that I tried for a different question.

Comment: I guess the tag `neovim` isn't applicable either. It's about VSCode and its Vim extension. So neither vim nor neovim.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Solution

As this problem arose in Linux and, I already changed my settings in Xmodmap, it seems that VScode not respecting remappings with xkbmap is a known issue and **should be fixed by adding** `"keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode"` **in VScode's settings.json** and reopening VS.

Answer (score 2):

Press  CTRL + SHIFT + P  to open the command pallete.

Then, click on the settings button on any of the commands.

This opens the keybindings.

Search `extension.vim_escape`

Change this to CAPS_LOCK.

> The only issue with this is that it still capitalises things when you re-enter insert mode, so you have to press it twice.

Answer (score 0):

I see you already found a possible workaround, but I wonder if the 'xcape' tool
(`apt install xcape`) can help with the following in your bashrc?

```
# set capslock to escape key  
setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
xcape -e '#66=Escape'
```

Comment: It seems it also worked, but as the problem was isolated to VScode and I hadn't really encountered any problems in other applications, I didn't want to change my system config. I already used Xmodmap and looked good for me. However, it does seem to be a good alternative. Thanks for your answer!!